# How I can draw this shape?

Tags: diagrams

I want to draw this shape by tex-ive 2015, bout I don't know.
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: This is very useful package for draw this: http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tkz-euclide/tkz-euclide-screen.pdf

Comment: Can you do any part of it? If so, please show us what you have so far. [Draw height in Tikz triangle](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/277614) this should get you part of the way, showing how to draw normals from a line to the adjacent corner of a rectangle. [Label angle with tikz](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136971) shows you how to label an angle.

Answer (score 6):

If you follow the guidelines given in [Draw height in Tikz triangle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/277614) as suggested by @Torbjørn T., you can produce a code more or less like this.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{angles}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % Definition of the right angle
  \def\aeMarkRightAngle[size=#1](#2,#3,#4){%%
   \draw ($(#3)!#1!(#2)$) -- 
         ($($(#3)!#1!(#2)$)!#1!90:(#2)$) --
         ($(#3)!#1!(#4)$);}

  % Placing the coordinates
  \coordinate [label=left:$A$] (A) at (-4, -2);
  \coordinate [label=above:$B$] (B) at (0, 4);
  \coordinate [label=right:$C$] (C) at (4, -2);

  % Drawing the heights
  \draw [name path=line 1,dashed] (C) -- ($(A)!(C)!(B)$) coordinate[label=left:$D$,name=D];
  \draw [name path=line 2,dashed] (A) -- ($(B)!(A)!(C)$) coordinate[label=right:$E$,name=E];

  % Drawing the baricenter
  \path [name intersections={of=line 1 and line 2,by=H}];
  \node [fill=black,inner sep=1pt,label=90:$H$] at (H) {};

  % Drawing the sides
  \draw (A) -- node[sloped,above]{$c-a$} (D) -- node[sloped,above]{$a$}(B);
  \draw (B) -- node[sloped,above]{$a$} (E) -- node[sloped,above]{$c-a$}(C);
  \draw (C) -- (A);

  % Drawing angles
  \pic [draw, -, "$\theta$", angle eccentricity=1.5] {angle = A--B--C};
  \pic [draw, -, "$\pi-\theta$", angle eccentricity=1.5] {angle = A--H--C};
  \aeMarkRightAngle[size=6pt](C,D,B)
  \aeMarkRightAngle[size=6pt](B,E,A)

  % Adding last labels
  \path (A) -- node[sloped,above]{$b-h$} (H);
  \path (C) -- node[sloped,above]{$b-h$} (H);
  \path (D) -- node[sloped,above]{$h$} (H);
  \path (E) -- node[sloped,above]{$h$} (H);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The final results is as shown here:
[image: Triangle]

Answer (score 5):

Here's an example with [`tkz-euclide`](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tkz/tkz-euclide/doc/tkz-euclide-screen.pdf), take some time to read the manual, it has lots of features. Also see the manual for [`Tikz/PGF`](http://ftp.fau.de/ctan/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf), very useful since `tkz-euclide` is based on it. Please make sure you post at least something you've tried next time, even just to provide some information about the graphic you're drawing (for example in this case, I assymed you wanted an equilateral triangle, but you didn't specify that).

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% Get points for equilateral triangle and draw it
\tkzDefPoints{0/0/A, 8/0/C}
\tkzDefEquilateral(A,C)\tkzGetPoint{B}
\tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)

% perpendicular heights + intersection to find point H
\tkzDrawAltitude[dashed](B,C)(A) \tkzGetPoint{E}
\tkzDrawAltitude[dashed](A,B)(C) \tkzGetPoint{D}
\tkzInterLL(A,E)(C,D) \tkzGetPoint{H} \tkzDrawPoint[fill=black](H)

% Segment labels
\tkzLabelSegments[above,midway,sloped](A,D E,C){$c-a$}
\tkzLabelSegments[above,midway,sloped](D,B B,E){$a$}
\tkzLabelSegments[above,midway,sloped](A,H H,C){$b-h$}
\tkzLabelSegments[above,midway,sloped](D,H H,E){$h$}

% Angles and labels
\tkzMarkAngle[size=5mm](A,B,C) \tkzLabelAngle[pos=.7](A,B,C){$\theta$}
\tkzMarkAngle[size=5mm](A,H,C) \tkzLabelAngle[pos=.7](A,H,C){$\pi-\theta$}
\tkzMarkRightAngle(C,D,B)
\tkzMarkRightAngle(A,E,B)

% Point labels
\tkzLabelPoints[above](B,H)
\tkzLabelPoints[right](E,C)
\tkzLabelPoints[left](A,D)

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```